# Making a window appear out of clicking on a image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, image

So i have a series of images like the following:

```
   <div id="gallery-top-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_1786.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-top-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2178.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-top-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2196.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="gallery-content">
   <div id= "gallery-bottom-picture"><img src="images/IMG_2214.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-bottom-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2273.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-bottom-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2274.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-bottom-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2277.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
   <div id="gallery-bottom-picture"><img src= "images/IMG_2280.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"></div>
```

I want that when i click one of them, another dummy window appears on top of the current one with just the image i clicked on it, could someone tell me how to do that on javascript? thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research or tried any javascript yet?

Comment: Why not use Lightbox??

Comment: Thanks cam i'll check it out... Sanpopo i did, but didn't find exactly what i was looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this `<a>` link tag to your images:

`<a href="javascript:void window.open('YOUR-IMAGE.jpg', 'width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');">IMAGE HERE</a>`

...for example:

```
<div id="gallery-top-picture">
    <a href="javascript:void window.open('images/IMG_1786.jpg', 'width=250,height=250,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');">
        <img src= "images/IMG_1786.jpg" width="125" height="125" border="1"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not explain me very well, i'm sorry, i don't really want to open a new tab/window per se, i want to place an image on top of the whole content fading the rest of the content out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("img").click(function(){
var src = $(this).attr("src");
window.open(src, "Image", "height=200,width=200");});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as well, just customize the css to your liking. Click on an image, and the to return it to normal click on the background.

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/9SqjL/

```
onclick="expand(this);"
```

you would just use this function on your image tagss